# Can i use a linear shaft for a rotating tool?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to build a drum sander like one of these

1. https://youtu.be/eeiszkNAZbQ
2. https://youtu.be/ydVM7o7zqZY

While looking for a suitable shaft, I find a lot of linear shafts. From the name and pictures I guess, that their are mainly build for linear movement, not for a tool like a drum sander. So my questions are:

1. What kind of shaft should I look for? If google for [shaft 20mm steel](https://www.google.com/search?q=shaft%2020mm%20steel&oq=shaft%2020mm%20steel) I only get linear shafts.
2. I'm just building a diy tool for my self. It's used a few times a year for an hour or so. So maybe a linear shaft is good enough?

Answer (score 0):

So just choose a suitable diameter.

You could use 1" with suitable block bearings or perhaps 3/4" may also be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

No, linear shafts place greater emphasis on straigntess rather than roundness. That means linear shafts are straighter than rotary shafts but may be centerless ground which makes them lobed (they all might be, but I am unable to verify). If such a shaft is used in a rotary application it will concentrate forces and cause undue wear. That said, you might be willing to live with it.

If the linear shaft is not lobed, however, it will be better than a rotary shaft, assuming the correct OD and tolerance is available.